# How to Implement UIPageController in project

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uipageviewcontroller

I'm having a page which contains UITextView with some text in it, there is a option to change the chapter, I put the change chapter option in a button click.
My code for the next chapter and previous chapter is

```
-(void) leftswipedetected:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
   delegatee.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegatee.selectedChapter intValue] + 1];
    [delegatee reloadVerses];
    [self resetReadViewToVerse:1];
}
-(void) rightswipedetected:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    if(![delegatee.selectedChapter isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        delegatee.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegatee.selectedChapter intValue] - 1];
        [delegatee reloadVerses];
        [self resetReadViewToVerse:1]; 
    }   
}
```

my question is how can I implement this chapter navigation with the help of `UIPageController` in ios5?. I just want to look like in iBook. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Nothing like `UIPageViewController` in iOS , it's UIPageControl and it just provides you with a UI type pagecontrol and you to change the chapter programmatically on tap on UIPagecontrol or or you may attach a UISwipeGesture to it.

[UIPageControl Tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/)

[Anothe one](http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/09/26/uipagecontrol-uiscrollview/)

Comment: so it it possible to change the chapter like page curl with the help of page control?

Comment: but the problem is i don't have the scrollview or ay separate view controller to change chapter,its all in oneviewcontroller

Comment: UIPageControl is simply a ui wherein you can define numberOfPages ,sizeForNumberOfPages:,etc .You can implement whatever effect you want to.In case of curl effect you will have to use UIView Animation(but why pagecontrol then?)Anyway yes it is possible

Comment: what are pages of your chapter?

Comment: there is no page actually,the text only changes in the textview ,i just want a page curl like iBook to change the chapter menz change the text,thats all

Comment: You can just use UIView Animation for that

Comment: yess u r correct,but UIView animation page curl doesn't seems like iBook like pagecurl

Comment: There is a UIPageViewController as of iOS6, just to add to the confusion. :)